# How can a player exist at a location that is not expressly defined?

Tags: coordinates

How do video games like Minecraft know how to place characters on an infinitely complex plane? For example, the game knows the character's place up to 10 or more decimal places and can display them at that location, but it only stores the blocks on the integer values. Here are other ways that I have thought about on how to phrase this question, because I know that I'm not being very clear:

- How can a player exist at a non-integer location?
- How can a player exist at a location that is not expressly defined?
- How do non-existent coordinates contain players, even if they don't exist?
- How can a game depict a player on coordinates it has not expressly stored?

I understand that the coordinates can be simply saved as doubles, but in order to store all the coordinates that a player could exist on would create a simply enormous file.

Comment: The key part of Josh's answer is `multiple coordinate systems`. Simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

A player *can't* exist at a location that isn't defined, because computers are discrete things. Bits in any representation of a number (integer or floating point) are either set or they are not set and the pattern they create defines a particular number which we interpret as location.

That doesn't mean you can't have multiple coordinate systems though. Just because you might define blocks in a Minecraft-like world with integers (because they will always exist at integer positions and never anything in-between) doesn't mean you cannot use floating point coordinates for the player or other objects, which allow you to represent the fact that there might be two blocks at X 1 and X 2, but the player is currently halfway between them at X 1.5.

In such an interpretation, I suppose you could say that the player's position is not "expressly stored" or representable in the block coordinate system, but it's certainly defined and expressible in the player's coordinate system and it's trivial to convert between them. You tend to need to convert between them in cases like rendering, where you want to put them all in the same coordinate system. At that point it's simply a matter of choosing a common coordinate system with the appropriate granularity. Sure, most floats can't represent numbers like 0.00000000000000000000134 accurately, but that's probably not relevant for the scale of your game.

You may also find [this question about representing positions in a large world](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104139/how-can-i-represent-location-in-a-massive-world) relevant, because the it's also common to use hierarchical or chunk-based coordinates in these really large worlds. This helps you combat the precision and range issue that the inherently-finite nature of computers impart on your numbers. Using two coordinates ("chunk" coordinate, and local coordinate with that chunk) is similar to my first example; you can't necessarily represent all *values* in all coordinate systems *simultaneously*, but you can do local conversions where it matters. For example when rendering you generally only consider a certain fixed number of chunks visible around the player and can choose a coordinate system for rendering that makes it possible for you to map everything together with an appropriate resolution for the task of rendering.